# Taking Previous Months' Date Automatically in PLSQL

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, rdbms

Hello I have a procedure and questions about it. This procedure is used for extracting data then inserting them into one table. When I test my code, I have to enter some parameters for executing procedure.

```
`--this is how I execute the procedure
begin
    GPU_DATA_EXTRACTOR(to_date('31/08/2021','DD/MM/YYYY'));
end;`
```

But what I want to do is that when the billdate parameter is NULL, the procedure should execute last day of the previous month as a parameter automatically. How can I make this change? I am open to any update advices thank you from now.
Updated the script below.

```
        create or replace procedure GPU_DATA_EXTRACTOR_TEST(pid_billdate DATE DEFAULT LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1))) is
c_limit   CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 10000;

CURSOR c1 IS
SELECT DISTINCT intl_prod_id
      FROM apld_bill_rt abr,
           acct_bill ab
      WHERE abr.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT'
          AND abr.TAX_CATG_ID = 'NOTAX'
          AND abr.acct_bill_id = ab.acct_bill_id
          AND ab.bill_date = pid_billdate;

TYPE prod_ids_t IS TABLE OF apld_bill_rt.intl_prod_id%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
l_prod_ids   prod_ids_t;
begin

   execute immediate 'truncate table GPU_INV_TEST';

  OPEN c1;

  LOOP
     FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO l_prod_ids LIMIT c_limit;
     
     EXIT WHEN l_prod_ids.COUNT = 0;

    FORALL indx IN 1 .. l_prod_ids.COUNT
    
      INSERT INTO GPU_INV_TEST
         SELECT AB.ACCT_BILL_ID,
                AB.BILL_NO,
                AB.INV_ID,
                AB.BILL_DATE,
                ba2.bill_acct_id,
                ba1.bill_acct_id parent_bill_acct_id,
                AB.DUE_DATE,
                PG.CMPG_ID,
                ABR.NET_AMT,
                AB.DUE_AMT,
                P.PROD_NUM,
                pds.DST_ID,
                ABR.DESCR,
                p.intl_prod_id
           FROM apld_bill_rt abr,
                acct_bill ab,
                prod p,
                FCBSADM.PROD_DST pds,
                bill_acct_prod bap,
                bill_acct ba1,
                bill_acct ba2,
                prod_cmpg pg
          WHERE ab.intl_bill_acct_id = ba1.intl_bill_acct_id
                AND AB.ACCT_BILL_ID = ABR.ACCT_BILL_ID
                AND ba1.intl_bill_acct_id = ba2.parent_bill_acct_id
                AND ba2.intl_bill_acct_id = bap.intl_bill_acct_id
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = abr.intl_prod_id
                AND ABR.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT'
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = pds.intl_prod_id
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = p.intl_prod_id
                AND p.intl_prod_id = pg.intl_prod_id(+)
                AND ABR.intl_prod_id = l_prod_ids(indx)
UNION
    SELECT AB.ACCT_BILL_ID,
                AB.BILL_NO,
                AB.INV_ID,
                AB.BILL_DATE,
                ba1.bill_acct_id,
                ba1.bill_acct_id parent_bill_acct_id,
                AB.DUE_DATE,
                PG.CMPG_ID,
                ABR.NET_AMT,
                AB.DUE_AMT,
                P.PROD_NUM,
                pds.DST_ID,
                ABR.DESCR,
                p.intl_prod_id
           FROM apld_bill_rt abr,
                acct_bill ab,
                prod p,
                FCBSADM.PROD_DST pds,
                bill_acct_prod bap,
                bill_acct ba1,
                prod_cmpg pg
          WHERE ab.intl_bill_acct_id = ba1.intl_bill_acct_id
                AND AB.ACCT_BILL_ID = ABR.ACCT_BILL_ID
                --AND ba1.intl_bill_acct_id = ba2.parent_bill_acct_id
                AND ba1.intl_bill_acct_id = bap.intl_bill_acct_id
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = abr.intl_prod_id
                AND ABR.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT'
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = pds.intl_prod_id
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = p.intl_prod_id
                AND p.intl_prod_id = pg.intl_prod_id(+)
                AND ABR.intl_prod_id = l_prod_ids(indx);

      
    COMMIT;  
    
    END LOOP;
   CLOSE c1;
end;
```

Comment: @Gar what do you think about that issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a default value for your parameters.  Take the following function as an example:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sf_showDefault
(
  p_in DATE DEFAULT LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1))
)
RETURN DATE
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN p_in;
END sf_showDefault;
/
```

When no parameters are entered it gets a truncated `SYSDATE` and subtracts one month, then if finds the last day of that month. All the function does is return that data (or the one that you pass in...if you feel like it).

Here is a DBFiddle showing the effect of `DEFAULT` parameters ([LINK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e36f743c6b2e84a81962151e93caeff9))

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Which line should I add this function inside procedure do you think? My second question that what is going to execution scripts if it works? (My assume is that begin
    GPU_DATA_EXTRACTOR;
end;  But not sure

Comment: @burakzbc  The function is just an example.  If you want to use it in your procedure, just copy `DEFAULT LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1))` and put it after the word `DATE` in your parameter definition.

Comment: Hello, the definition is compiled successfully but I have only records about the date 31/8/2021 in developer environment. So when I execute the procedure for test without parameter it works but doesnt insert anything into the table. what should be reason do you think? Is it about I have only record in august or something else? I tested with "-2". It doesnt insert too

Comment: My first line is this by the way// create or replace procedure GPU_DATA_EXTRACTOR_TEST(pid_billdate DATE DEFAULT LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1)))

Comment: As we are currently in October, I would expect it to run for September.  If you need to test it with August data, just change the `ADD_MONTHS` parameter to `-2` instead of `-1`.  *JUST FOR THE TESTING*